# Could not find or load java main class

Tags: java

I have a very basic program in java,the filename is MainClass1.java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Student{
    String name;
    int roll_number;
    double marks;
    Student(String s,int r,double m)
    {
        this.name=s;
        this.roll_number=r;
        this.marks=m;
    }
}
class MainClass1{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        String name="Sourav";
        int roll_number=25;
        double marks=70.50;
        Student student1=new Student(name,roll_number,marks);
        System.out.println("The student is "+student1.name+" and his roll number is "+student1.roll_number+" and his marks is "+student1.marks);
    }
}
```

It compiles fine,however when I am trying to run it by

```
java Mainclass1
```

it shows an error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Mainclass1
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: MainClass1 (wrong name: Mainclass1)
```

I know its a very basic issue,but unable to figure out the issue.

Please help anyone

Comment: Try `java MainClass1` (with a capital C).  Java is case sensitive.

Comment: Yes,tried and resolved,sorry for this silly mistake

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "Could not find or load main class" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean)

Answer (score 1):

When you run a program (that is, when you call `java ...`) the JVM needs to know where to start running the code. It looks for a public static method named `main`, which takes an array of `String` as input, and is defined on whatever class is named in the `.java` file.

So:

1. verify that your file is named "`MainClass1.java`" – the filename and the class name need to match
2. verify that the class includes the `public` modifier, so change this:

   ```
   class MainClass1 {
   ...
   }
   ```

   to this:

   ```
   public class MainClass1 {
   ...
   }
   ```